# Generar el mismo UUID basado en una cadena en Kotlin y PHP

Tags: php, android, kotlin, backend, uuid

Requiero generar un `UUID` a partir de una cadena de texto. El problema es que no coinciden los UUID entre el que genero en Kotlin con el PHP, es decir necesito que el UUID coincide por la misma cadena generado en Kotlin y PHP.

```kotlin
val str = "˙ᵕ˙"
val uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(str.toByteArray())
```

Eso genera el siguiente UUID `83f42160-9ff5-33b2-889f-2a681abfab74`

El problema lo tengo en PHP que no ser como conseguir ese mismo UUID, he buscado por internet y dicen que con la siguiente libreria https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Pero mi skill de PHP es muy bajo, alguien sabe como se usa esa libreria y un ejemplo con la misma cadena para ver si genera el mismo UUID?

**edito**

Con la respuesta de @nachospiu he creado lo siguiente

```php
$str = "˙ᵕ˙";
vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(md5($str), 4));
```

Genera el siguiente UUID `83f42160-9ff5-83b2-889f-2a681abfab74`

Pero hay una pequeña variación en el tercer segmento `83b2` deberia ser `33b2`

Comment: basado en el SO original, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430967/way-to-create-common-name-based-uuids-in-java-and-php

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer lo que tu necesitas es el hash md5 de esa cadena, puedes utilizar la función `md5()` de [php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php).

```
<?php
      $uuid = md5("˙ᵕ˙");
?>
```

$uuid tiene almacenada la cadena: '83f421609ff583b2889f2a681abfab74'

#### Actualizada

No se mucho sobre el tema, pero estuve leyendo un poco, y creo haber encontrado el porque de la diferencia en el md5 generado por php y el UUID (md5) generado con la librería de kotlin.

La función **UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(ByteArray)** genera un UUID de tipo 3 a partir del array de btyes pasado como parámetro. El UUID de tipo 3 utiliza el algoritmo de hashing MD5 de 128 bits.

xxxxxxxx-xxxx-Bxxx-Axxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

La función estática `nameUUIDFromBytes()` trunca el resultado del hash (md5) en 128 bits y luego reemplzar la variante del UUID (A) y la versión (B).

La variante se determina por los 3 bits mas significativos de A.

La versión describe el tipo de UUID.

Según entiendo `nameUUIDFromBytes()` modifica ligeramente el MD5 generado, por lo que mi respuesta no contesta tu pregunta. Deberías probar la librería que figura en la pregunta que agregaste en los comentarios, a ver si se comporta igual a la clase UUID.

Comment: veo que hay una variación 83f421609ff5...83....b2889f2a681abfab74, el 83 deberia ser 33

Comment: Si, no lo había notado, es raro.

Comment: pero ahora acabo de probar md5 en ambos kotlin y php dan el mismo, mirare de adaptar con eso y formatear el md5 en kotlin que parezca UUID y ya estará